# NativeScript modal take full screen on ios

Tags: android, ios, angular, modal-dialog, nativescript

i have tried to add modal on my nativescript project it work as expected on android but on ios it take the full height and width of screen it should shown partially.

i have created a separate angular component to open it i use below code.

and it works fine on android but on ios it open modal as full screen.

```
public showModal(fullscreen: boolean, animated = true, stretched = false) {
    const options: ModalDialogOptions = {
        context: { promptMsg: "This is the prompt message!" },
        fullscreen,
        animated,
        stretched,
        viewContainerRef: this.vcRef,
    };

    this.modal.showModal(ModalContent, options).then((res: string) => {
        this.result = res || "empty result";
    });
```

the modal should open partially on ios as android.
is any workaround for it please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think iPhone supports popup kind of modal, only iPad supports it. A workaround is to use the fullscreen modal, make the background transparent and put your content in the middle.

If you are familiar with native apis, I guess it could be done by limiting the frame size for the modal.

Comment: thanks for your answer there is workaround available where we can put our modal as a child component and pass an event to show and hide, i will post the code if succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I have found a PR in the nativescript-angular repository that seems to implement iOS non-fullscreen modals with the following Code in the ModalDialogOptions

```
 ios: {
        presentationStyle: UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    }
```